# How to check https response code in bulk with max performance?

Tags: php, python, curl, httprequest, httpresponse

I need to check http response codes frequently on tens of thousands of URLs. What would be the most efficient way in PHP or python to do this?

In PHP I startet of with sequential requests:

```
function get_http_response_code($domain1) {
  $headers = get_headers($domain1);
  return substr($headers[0], 9, 3);
}

IF ($check){
    foreach ($check as $id => $url) {
        $get_http_response_code[$id] = get_http_response_code($url);
        echo $url." -> ".$get_http_response_code[$id]."\n";
    }
}
```

This takes about 0.5 - 1 s per request:

```
200 request time in ms: 920.52ms 
200 request time in ms: 1123.08ms 
200 request time in ms: 1327.84ms 
200 request time in ms: 610.86ms 
200 request time in ms: 1122.79ms 
200 request time in ms: 1226.19ms 
200 request time in ms: 1120.73ms 
200 request time in ms: 917.12ms 
200 request time in ms: 851.57ms
```

I am trying to eitherimprove or do several requests in parallel. What would be the best way to perform this task?

Comment: There are multiple ways to achieve this in python, one you can consider is https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/. I've voted to close as I don't think that this question is specific enough to get a helpful response and there are already a lot of resources online that address making concurrent http requests.

Comment: python threading and future requests

Comment: @SuperShoot Thank you for your help. I looked into the library and understand that there are multiple possibilites. My question however is specific enought in my view as I am looking into improving the total time of processing through the provided PHP algo or any other solution. I also updated the question including now the response times.